# How to install GWT plugin in the browser?

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to download GWT plugin for say Firefox on one machine and install it 
later on another machine.
I don't want to install it automatically.
The machine on which I want to install the plugin is not connected to internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download gwt browser plugin's from the page: http://www.gwtproject.org/missing-plugin/ . Instead of installing(clicking on the link), right click and save the plugin file.

Comment: Thanks Hilbrand, got the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply download it, either at [the missing plugin page](http://gwt.google.com/missing-plugin/MissingPlugin.html), or [directly from svn](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn/trunk/plugins/MissingPlugin/src/com)
in both cases you can download the file. to install it, simply drag it onto your firefox.